# Firebase storage downloadURL file structure

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-storage

So I'm using firebase storage to upload my website files. Here is an example of the directory structure:

```
Project
├── index.html
├── css
│   └── style.css
└── js
    └── mainScript.js
```

So I'm uploading these files to firebase in this structure, but I notice that the downloadURL that's returned is not very friendly in preserving this structure..

For example, when I set the src of an iframe to the downloadURL for the index.html.. the iframe page is missing the style and mainScript files.

This is how the downloadURL looks for index.html:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/App_ID.appspot.com/o/index.html?alt=media&token=some_uid

This is how the downloadURL looks for style.css:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/App_ID.appspot.com/o/css%2Fstyle.css?alt=media&token=some_uid
etc..

Of course the index.html file is looking for the style.css file at:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/App_ID.appspot.com/o/css/style.css

but results in 404.

Is there a way around this problem?

> PS, Of course I don't want to force the user to change the urls in their files...

Comment: I am in the very same situation, wanting to upload a Unity WebGL game into storage and loading it into an iFrame, but because of this weird URL random generation, file tree is broken and the iFrame cannot load. It's a pity since AWS allows thats properly for ages. Have you figured a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the storage to save your website files! Use Firebase hosting instead ...
Firebase storage is designed for storing upload/download files (image, audio, etc.)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/

Comment: My intention isn't to store my own website files.. I'm trying to allow users of my website to upload their own website (of course without server-scripts.. well with Firebase api that kind of blurs the line but probably you know what I mean)

Basically, my assumption with Firebase Storage was that it would be like Firebase Hosting except we can access the storage programmatically rather than just through CLI..