# Set cache to files in Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, json, caching, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a [PWA](https://discipulado-7b14b.firebaseapp.com/) running on Firebase. My image files are hosted on the Firebase Storage. I've noticed my browser doesn't save cache for files loaded from the storage system. The browser requests the files for every page refresh. It causes unnecessary delay and traffic.

[image: Network stats]

My JS script loads the files from the Firebase Storage's download link, example: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/discipulado-7b14b.appspot.com/o/book3.png?alt=media&token=65b2cde7-c8a4-45da-a743-401759663c17.

Can I cache those requests?

**UPDATE**

According to these [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38121038/2684718) I shouldn't use Firebase Storage to host files from my site. Just to manage downloads and uploads from users. Is this correct?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.SettableMetadata#cacheControl

Comment: For Storage, you can set the metadata on a file, like `contentType` or `cacheControl`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`cacheControl` for Storage : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.SettableMetadata#cacheControl

---

You'll have better serving with Hosting, and deployment with the firebase CLI is extremely simple.  I think by default the Cache-Control on images in Hosting is 2 hours, and you can increase it globally with the .json.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers

Hosting can scale your site and move it to different edge nodes closer to where the demand is.  Storage is limited to buckets, but you can specify a bucket for Europe, one for China, on for North America, etc..

Storage is better for user file uploads and Hosting was for static content (although they are rolling out dynamic Hosting with cloud functions I think)

Comment: Thanks, bro! You helped a lot!  :D

Comment: In this answer, "Hosting" means Firebase Hosting, and "Storage" means Firebase Storage. Both are services provided by Firebase. Just for clarity.

Comment: I had the same issue and found the solution to serve Cloud Storage files by Firebase Hosting. Now we get the benefits from both products. :)
https://dev.to/dbanisimov/building-image-cdn-with-firebase-15ef

Comment: FYI - bandwidth on 'hosting' plan is more expensive than the 'storage' equivalent plan.

Comment: telling people to potentially abandon their stack and use firebase hosting is not good (assuming the host is bundled in with the stack like with Vercel + Next)

Answer (score 15):

Putting the pieces together for any future references here

First,

```
// Create file metadata to update
var newMetadata = {
  cacheControl: 'public,max-age=4000',
}
```

Then,

```
storageRef.put(file, newMetadata)
```

Comment: Depecrated by now. You need to use `putFile()` instead.

Comment: with firebase 9, you have to set updateMetadata(imageRef, newMetadata);

Answer (score 5):

`storageRef.updateMetadata(yourMetadata)` might be the solution you need.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata#update_file_metadata

or

`storageRef.put(file, yourMetadata)`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_files

Answer (score 4):

Also, Is possible to change the cache control of an existent resource accessing Google Cloud Console. (So, don't need to reupload with the cache metadata)

Access the console and go to 'Cloud Storage'.
Browse to your bucket and file, where you find 'edit metadata'.

Here, you can put the cache control policy:

[image: Edit metadata for object]

Comment: So, if you tried (like me) to find it in the Firebase console - it's not there. The key is to access the file through Google's Cloud Console and NOT through the firebase console...

Answer (score 3):

To complement the answer, you can also use a service worker, maybe with [workbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox), with a `cacheFirst` strategy to cache all images into the user browser. Then, after first cache, the images will be load from local cache first.

If there's no cache, then the images will be requested from Firebase Storage, where the images can also be cached if you specified the `cacheControl` property in file metadata or if you is using Firebase Hosting with custom header `Cache-Control` for images.

Comment: I'm using workbox for this as well, however you may need to employ the staleWhileRevalidate or networkFirst strategies in workbox, because you are requesting a third party file. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/handle-third-party-requests

Answer (score 2):

**Use Serviceworker for that.**

You can save the urls without the token in cache and fetch them later.

This way changes in tokens will not affect you caching.

To cache without token, use something like

```
cacheUrl = url.origin + url.pathname.substr(0, url.pathname.length - urlPath.length) + urlPath;
```

and then `cache.put(cacheUrl, response);`