# How can I set cache-control on firebase console ? [SPEED UP Firebase Storage]

Tags: performance, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I was previously on S3 buckets but recently decided to go for firebase because I use other of their services.

Choice was **firebase hosting** or **firebase storage**.
 - Hosting seems faster but, needs a full deploy at each update
 - Storage allow me to upload only one file to the bucket if needed but is slower

Here's my issue : I added all my files in **/images/** of the default bucket.

I can't find on the firebase console where to set **cache-control**.

How can I acheive that ? How can I gain more speed on firebase storage ?

Is there a default CDN on firebase Cloud Storage or can it be used with a CDN to have better speed an caching ?

PS: All my files are publicly readable as they are just images
PS 2: I can set cache-control when my users upload images throught my app, my question concerns images imported from the console interface

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44124537/set-cache-to-files-in-firebase-storage

Comment: I've already check that and if you read my question again i'm asking how to do this through the interface not programmatically. Besides, the answer on that thread lacks of code to explain what to do so is irrelevant for me ayway